# Swift jpegData(compressionQuality:) returns larger image when compressionQuality 0 is used compared to 0.1

Tags: swift, uiimage

For the last hour or so I was wondering why my images are still large on highest compression using `uiImage.jpegData(compressionQuality: 0)`.

If I use compressionQuality `0` my ~5Mb image gets compressed to a file size of ~2Mb. But as soon as I use `0.1` my file size reduces to 700Kb.

I figured that out after a found this [Post about HEIC Image Compression for iOS (www.raywenderlich.com)](https://www.raywenderlich.com/4726843-heic-image-compression-for-ios#toc-anchor-006). The sample project is the perfect demonstration.

**Why is that?** Is that a bug or a feature or am I doing something wrong here?

edit:
Sample code:

```
let sometimesLargerThan:Data = UIImage("imageInBundle.jpg").jpegData(compressionQuality: 0)

let this:Data = UIImage("imageInBundle.jpg").jpegData(compressionQuality: 0.1)
```

Comment: Can you add a code snippet?

Comment: Download the sample project I linked above from raywenderlich.com. This simple iOS project is the perfect demonstration.

Answer (score 1):

The Bug is still around today. It seems like .1 compression quality is the smallest you can get, because as soon as you go smaller (.05 or even .00) the image size is larger again.

Answer (score 0):

That's odd - here's the url for the function - compressionQuality.

Do the dimensions of the image are same for both compressions? That's only thing I'm thinking of this otherwise, it might be a bug.

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiimage/1624115-jpegdata

compressionQuality
The quality of the resulting JPEG image, expressed as a value from 0.0 to 1.0. The value 0.0 represents the maximum compression (or lowest quality) while the value 1.0 represents the least compression (or best quality).